HPE Smart Array P408i 2GB experiencing a performance drop
I have two HP ProLiant ML 350 GEN 10 with a RAID 10 SSD Samsung disks and HPE SmartArray P408 with 2 GB cache. It has good performance:

When copying large files, performance drops after two minutes...
From 10 GB NIC to P408i: (from 900 MB/s to 50 MB/s):

From internal NVME disc to P408i: (from 900 MB/s to 40 MB/s):

From internal SSD_AHCI to P408i (from 550 MB/s to 36 MB/s)

I installed both SSD and NVMe PCI-E to the server and there's no drop in performance.
FROM 10 GB NIC to NVME:

FROM 10 GB NIC to AHCI _SSD:

I have another HP ProLiant ML350  GEN 10 with the same SmartArray controller, same firmware, same driver, same cache configuration, and does not have this problem.

Hope someone can help me!!

What exact drive's model do you have?

Samsung SSD 870 1TB

If it is 870 QVO model, then such performance is expected while copying large capacity. This model is very slow. Look here at iometer test - https://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/samsung-870-qvo-sata-ssd/3

The 870 QVO is a low-end disk which sucks for large write loads. It also won't last long with such a workload.

The issue here may be the limitations of the Samsung QVO 870 SSDs in use.
When using a Samsung QVO 870 SSD, the initial write speed using the SLC cache is typically around 500 MB/s. However, once the SLC cache is exhausted, the write speed drops significantly as the drive switches to QLC NAND, which can slow down to approximately 80-160 MB/s depending on the workload and the specific model. This drop occurs because QLC NAND is much slower at writing data compared to SLC NAND.
From: https://www.anandtech.com/show/15887/the-samsung-870-qvo-1tb-4tb-ssd-review-qlc-refreshed/2

The SLC caches on the 870 QVOs run out right on schedule, at 42 GB and 78 GB. Write performance drops precipitously but is stable thereafter, for the rest of the drive fill process. This behavior hasn't changed meaningfully from the 860 QVO.

Do you have access to better disks for this purpose?

To paraphrase, OP is using desktop-grade SSD attached to a SATA RAID controller and expecting Server performance, (ie, continuous) ?

No... SATA SSD and NVME are just for testing....  I will try to replace all SAMSUNG EVO 870 ... It's only a backup server and don't want to spend too much money on enterprise ssd .  The other ML350GEN10 works flowsly with  4 X CRUCIAL MX500 SSD.

@JordiAuladell I think you have enough information to resolve this issue. Did this answer help you?


After replacing all SAMSUNG 870QVO drives to CRUCIAL MX500...problem has gone!!!
Thank you so much @ewwhite for your answer!!!
